# Azure webapp files loading slow

Tags: performance, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a problem with an Azure WebApp that is running very slow (loading times +3min with a cleaned cache).
The web app is a single page application, so the first load is the biggest.
Always On is enabled.
The tier is currently at B2.

[An example of the slow loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3Wqt.jpg)

The metrics of the application plan are the following:
CPU is at 6.3% average (25% peak). 
Memory is at 33.7% average (40% peak).

Other applications seem to be loading also slow. It's really the loading of a file that seems to be slow. 
When using the development tools of Firefox I can see the network communication and timings. For example the file vendor.bundle.js (6.77MB): The browser needs to wait 4709 ms (seems to be too long?) Then it takes 112374 ms to receive it?

My location is Belgium. The location of the WebApp is West Europe. I found [this very usefull azure speedtest](http://azurespeedtest.azurewebsites.net/) to determine if that would be the problem. [Seems like that shouldn't be the problem (latency of 78ms).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZaqA.jpg)

My internet speed could have been the problem as suggested, so I did a speedtest. 
[90.47 Mbps Download and 18.00 Mbps upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQXXx.jpg). So that seems to be OK for me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There's several things you could check: are the bundles created beforehand or are they generated the first time they're asked for? Are other static resources from that WebApp slow as well? Is the Web App busy building an in-mem cache or something like that? Are there lots and lots of requests pending stressing the App Service Plan? To know this you should check the CPU & memory usage of the App Service Plan. _In short_: gives us some more info, since this is too little to go on.

Comment: Thank you Rick.
The CPU is at 6.3% average (25% peak).
The memory is at 33.7% average (40% peak).
Other applications seem to be loading also slow.

It's really the loading of a file that is slow. When using the development tools of Firefox I can see the network communication and timings. For example the file vendor.bundle.js (6.77MB):
The browser needs to wait 4709 ms (seems to be too long?)
Then it takes 112374 ms to receive it?

Comment: @Thomas: please update your question with the metrics instead of adding them in the comments

Comment: Done, thank you for the hint, @CSharpRocks

Comment: According to your mentioned screenshot, it seems that it is related to **your location and you website location** or **slow Internet speed**. Which location is your website? If your website and your location are not same, please have a try to publish it in the  same location with you.

Comment: Thank you @TomSun. I'm in Belgium, the app is in West Europe. Could that be the problem? Average latency would be 75ms?

Comment: According to your added information, it seems that it is ok for you.  You also could open an azure [support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for more help.

Comment: @TomSun. I already have a support ticket open for this, but I wanted to ask the community too. If there's a solution through support, I'll let you all know.

Comment: @ThomasNauwelaerts any luck?